# Chrome doesn't respect overflow hidden when changing style with :hover pseudo class

Tags: css, google-chrome, html, css-transforms

I have a circle div (`border-radius: 50%`) containing two more divs transformed to represent circle segments, which i get by setting `overflow: hidden` at the parent container (outer circle):

[image]
I want the circle segments to have their background color changed on mouse over, which works fine in Firefox and IE, but Chrome seems to not respect the `overflow: hidden` setting of the parent container on hover.

[image: After hover in chrome]

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rFrcu/

Any ideas?

Comment: Wow! seems like a google-chrome bug. I don't know anything about this, but is really strange that works on IE and FF, and not in Chrome. What did you already tried? I must add that on IE isn't working properly too. Red segment is superimposed on the yellow segment.

Comment: I tried different combinations of absolute/relative positioning, display options (block, inline-block) and z-indices, neither of them worked. Which version of IE are you using? IE 10 works for me.

Comment: I'm using IE 9 at my work. I will take a look on your example and try to get something when I go back home, if I have time and it's not already solved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN'
    'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' lang='ru' xml:lang='ru'>
<head>
<title>circle</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.node {
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    background: blue;
    opacity: 0.9;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.button {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin-x: 0px;
    -webkit-transform-origin-y: 0px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.button1 {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) skew(30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg) skew(30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) skew(30deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg) skew(30deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg) skew(30deg);
}
.button2 {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg) skew(60deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) skew(60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) skew(60deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg) skew(60deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg) skew(60deg);
}
.circ {
    height: 200%;
    width: 200%;
    border-radius:100%;
    left: -100%;
    top: -100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.button1 .circ {
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-30deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-30deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-30deg);
    transform: skew(-30deg);
}
.button2 .circ {
    background-color: yellow;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-60deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-60deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-60deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-60deg);
    transform: skew(-60deg);
}
.circ:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="node">
  <div class="button button1">
    <div class="circ"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="button button2">
    <div class="circ"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN'
    'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' lang='ru' xml:lang='ru'>
<head>
<title>circle</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.node {
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    background: blue;
    opacity: 0.9;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.button {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    border-radius:0 0 100% 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin-x: 0px;
    -webkit-transform-origin-y: 0px;
}
.button.button1 {
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.button.button2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
    transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.button.end {
    background-color: blue;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
.button.end:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="node">
  <div class="button button1"></div>
  <div class="button button2"></div>
  <div class="button end"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting approach making `overflow: hidden` obsolete. I forked the jsFiddle to reflect your solution: [http://jsfiddle.net/bjv2t/](http://jsfiddle.net/bjv2t/). What i miss is a way to control the width of the segments without the need to overlap them, which makes it difficult to dynamically fill up the circle with segments.